# How to determine if an OS X dylib was linked with -flat_namespace

Tags: xcode, macos, dynamic-linking, dylib, dyld

I have a third party OS X dylib that I'm using in my app and don't have easy access to its creator.  I'd like to determine if it was linked with -flat_namespace.  Is that possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run `otool -hV` on the library.  If you don't see `TWOLEVEL`, then it was linked with `-flat-namespace`.  For example:

```
twolevel.dylib:
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64  X86_64        ALL  0x00       DYLIB     8        672   NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL NO_REEXPORTED_DYLIBS
```

versus

```
flat.dylib:
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64  X86_64        ALL  0x00       DYLIB     8        672 DYLDLINK NO_REEXPORTED_DYLIBS
```