# What does "expected in: flat namespace" mean?

Tags: macos, dynamic-linking, dyld

The OS X dynamic loader often gives errors like

```
Symbol not found: <some symbol name>
Referenced from: <lib location>
Expected in: flat namespace
```

If you [search for the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=expected+in+flat+namespace) you'll find a ton of errors that have it. I understand roughly that the problem is an incorrect linking, but none of the answers explain what "flat namespace" means here, exactly.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the same error when linking dylib from executable that posses symbol  used by that dylib. if I compile the executable in Xcode under debug  mode, it works.. but switching to release mode, and the process refuse to start with the same error you mentions. Any idea what trigger this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This answer only applies to macOS 10.4 and higher. E.g. In previous versions of 'OSX' flat-namespaces were the default. And on Windows 
 resolving can also work slightly different, depending on the mode though.*

### **Prolog**

Let's first talk about the background of namespaces. In MacOS there are two so-called namespaces available. [Two-level namespace](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/compiling/compiling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002850-BCIHJBBF) and [single namespace](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/ld.1.html#sect7) (also known as flat-namespace).

**Flat-namespace**

Each process has a huge table which contains all symbols (functions, external variables, ..). When a library gets loaded it might depend on a symbol and therefore can look in the flat-namespace to find which other library or executable 'offers' it. After all symbols were found, the library adds his own symbols to the list. One huge disadvantage is the amount of possible collisions. A process might load two or more libraries with the same symbol names. It is up to the OS how to deal with collisions, but in most cases it's simply undefined behaviour and leads to a crash because of mixed libraries.

**Two-level namespace**

In a two-level namespace, instead of a plain table with symbol names, the symbols are saved with name and their library name (so where they come from). A library that relies on a symbol needs to know exactly from which library it wants to get the symbol XYZ resolved.

### **What that means for your problem**

The lib was obviously compiled with a flat-namespace option and requires the symbol  to run properly. A solution is to load the library it depends on before the lib gets loaded that causes the problem.

[Also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553530/how-to-determine-if-an-os-x-dylib-was-linked-with-flat-namespace) interesting to find the solution to your problem:

> Run `otool -hV` on the library.  If you don't see `TWOLEVEL`, then it
>   was linked with `-flat-namespace`.

Comment: The background on symbol lookup makes this error so much easier to understand. Thanks for that.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the error while trying to run `psycopg2-binary` on macOS Big Sur.

Solution:

Remove psycopg2-binary and reinstall using the `--no-cache-dir`

Answer (score -2):

Uninstall:

```
pip uninstall psycopg2
```

Reinstall:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir psycopg2
```