# Using different boost versions in shared lib and executable file on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I am really newbie with development for Mac and I faced with strange behavior, which I can't find how to deal with.

I have a `mylib.dylib` file, compiled with `boost 1.80.0` as dependency, and an executable, that load the `mylib.dylib` and uses `boost 1.66.0`.

Boost statically linked in both cases. So, I expect that entire code inside the library is fully independent from executable binary. But it seems that Mac has another opinion).

When I call `dlopen`, some global object inside boost start to initialize and it's call `boost::system::system_category()` function. The function has absolutely different implementation in [1.66.0](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/boost/system/detail/error_code.ipp) and [1.80.0](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/boost/system/detail/system_category.hpp) versions. In short words, I realized that `mylib.dylib` calls `system_category()` from executable(1.66.0), not his own one(1.80.0).

`Disassembly view` proof:
[image]

When I started to google the problem, I have found a comment that describe `Flat-namespace` and `Two-level namespace` concepts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392862/4481855 . And the behavior of my binaries looks like it's compiled as `Flat-namespace` as it seems that executable file already have `system_category` symbol which somehow forced `mylib.dylib` to use it instead his own one, but I checked both files via `otool -hV` and it shows `TWOLEVEL` for both.

I have tried to load `mylib.dylib` via dlopen with different flags and combinations, but no success.

One more clue is that symbol dumber says, that `system_category` is `weak symbol` in `mylib.dylib`:

```
% nm -m libcompliance_engine.dylib | grep weak | grep system_category
00000000022205c8 (__DATA,__data) weak external __ZGVZN5boost6system15system_categoryEvE8instance
0000000000178aa0 (__TEXT,__text) weak external __ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv
000000000007bed0 (__TEXT,__text) weak external __ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv
0000000002220590 (__DATA,__data) weak external __ZZN5boost6system15system_categoryEvE8instance
```

What can I do to tell `mylib.dylib` to use his own implementation of `system_category`? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: *When I call `dlopen`, some global object inside boost start to initialize and it's call `boost::system::detail::system_category()` function.* It looks well working. mylib.dylib is linked with boost 1.80.0, `boost::system::detail::system_category()` is from boost 1.80.0. boost 1.66.0 has `boost::system::system_category()`, another namespace. mylib.dylib can't call it.

Comment: My bad, I wrote names from my memory and made the mistake - "global object" calls `boost::system::system_category()`, no `details` namespace there

Comment: You are confusing something. `boost::system::system_category()` can't be called from mylib.dylib linked with `boost 1.80.0`. That name is unknown to the dylib library. You seem to have an issue in your code, and not in mylib.dylib initialization. You might set a breakpoint at `boost::system::system_category()` and watch the call stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem also described as "potentially possible scenario" here: [Two-level namespace and external symbols](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693813)

Fortunately, my teammate has found the solution: it has been fixed in `1.81.0` version by implementing `BOOST_DISABLE_EXPLICIT_SYMBOL_VISIBILITY` definition, so after upgrading boost from `1.80.0` to `1.81.0` the issue disappeared, as `system_category` is not a `weak symbol` anymore